# php array_filter function not found or invalid function name regardless of what I enter

Tags: php, arrays

I've never used the array_filter function before so giving it a go by no matter what I use as the function name it is giving me the error

```
Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function 'odd' not found or invalid function name in
```

I have even taken the steps of copying paste the example directly off the php manual page and it is giving me that same error. Code:

```
function odd($var) {
    // returns whether the input integer is odd
    return($var & 1);
 }

function calculate($res, $period, $elements, $per, $total, $brand = false) {

    $array1 = array("a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3, "d"=>4, "e"=>5);
    $array2 = array(6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);

    echo "Odd :\n";
    print_r(array_filter($array1, "odd"));
}
```

I really don't know where to go here. Usually when I'm having trouble I can copy and paste the code exact off the php manual page and work my way back from there but if their example isn't even working it makes it hard.

Comment: Hm? It works just fine for me, what's your PHP version?

Comment: Appears to be working http://codepad.org/GV2Kyp89. Is that the exact code or did you trim it down before posting?

Comment: Can you restart  PHP & Apache  .. it works fine on `4.3.0 - 5.4.9`

Comment: @YannisRizos php 5.4.4 on MAMP. Back into work today and it still giving me the same warning. I isolated the code completely in it's own program and it worked... I have no idea why it's not working within the class I have written. There are no other functions called "odd" so it can't be that

Comment: Show us how both your class and these functions are defined.

Answer (score 12):

I think in your case, function odd is not a standalone function but method of your class. In that case you should write

```
print_r(array_filter($array1, array($this,"odd")));
```

to run odd method from your class

Answer (score 0):

If your class is the same and you call a method in recursive then the
PHP does not know the method belongs each class or not that's why use
`$this` in an array:

```
array_filter($array1, array($this,"recursive"))

    public function customArrayFilter($logDate, $uid, $date)
    {
        $logDates = array($logDate);
        $result = array_filter($logDates, array($this, "recursive"));
        var_dump($result);
    }

    public function recursive($data)
    {
        return $data;
    }

   $this->customArrayFilter($data, 1, '2019-02-23');
```